# Problem runing Matlab R2013a in Ubuntu (aparently, something to do with Java)

Tags: 14.04, 15.04, java, matlab

I am having some troubles while trying to run Matlab R2013 on Ubuntu 15.04 (the same problem happens in 14.04 and 12.04 versions). When I try to run in from the terminal or using the Matlab icon, I get the following error message:

[image: Error while trying to run Matlab R2013a.]

**BUT** if I run it as super user, it works fine, but I get several other problems with that, for example, the applications that I developed in Matlab don't run.

What can I do in order to run Matlab as a regular user?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please check the ownership of your personal matlab settings directory `/home/santiago/.matlab`: by running matlab as super-user one time (using `sudo`?) you probably caused root to take ownership of it - making it unwriteable to anyone *except* root.

Comment: The problem is that I can't run it (even at the fisrt time) without using sudo...

Comment: And there is no .matlab file in my home directory...

Comment: If you are looking for the `.matlab` file using a file browser, you may need to select `Show hidden files` (Ctrl+H). If you are using the `ls` command you will need to add the `-A` or `-a` switch to see it.

Comment: OK, but the owner is not "sudo"...  I have the ownership of the folder and the files...

Comment: I tried [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB), but didn't work...

Comment: Please try `sudo chown -R santiago:santiago /home/santiago/.matlab` and then attempt to run matlab as your regular user. If there are errors this time, please [edit] your post to show them.

Comment: It worked! Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is clearly indicating an error with your user's write permissions on the file mentioned.

Anytime you run an application that saves configuration information in the user's home directory using `sudo`, you run the risk that the `root` user will take ownership of those files/directories, making them unwriteable for your regular user when you then try to run the application *without* `sudo`.

Usually this can be fixed easily by restoring the intended ownership using the `chown` command e.g.

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME/<confdir>
```

or this specific case

```
sudo chown -R santiago:santiago /home/santiago/.matlab
```